# Group_Concat Separator changes comma in result

Tags: mysql

I am using Group_Contat for a MySQL database pull.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(#__facileforms_subrecords.value ORDER BY #__facileforms_subrecords.id DESC SEPARATOR '|') AS inspectionvalue
```

In the result I have these things:

Array ( [inspectionvalue] => Good|2017-03-03|Fertilizing|Flower Bed Cultivation|Trim Lawn )

Good is one result
2017-03-03 is another result
Fertilizing|Flower Bed Cultivation|Trim Lawn is actually one result. It was at first a comma separated result coming from a multi-select list, so I thought separator would just separate the results and keep the multiselect list alone, but it didn't. Is there something I can use on the database pull that would not change the comma between 
Fertilizing,Flower Bed Cultivation,Trim Lawn, but the full results still with a pipe ie

Array ( [inspectionvalue] => Good|2017-03-03|Fertilizing,Flower Bed Cultivation,Trim Lawn )

After I pull the results I am exploding them based on pipe.

Comment: Can you at least show us some sample data?

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) need form any part of the answer; leastwise when spitting out an array.

Comment: Tim, The data that come out is the Array above.

Comment: Strawberry, sorry I don't understand you answer. I just wanted to know if there was a way of protecting the commas in the third result of Fertilizing,Flower Bed Cultivation,Trim Lawn